# Can one rake namespace reference a variable in another

Tags: rake, rakefile

I have 2 rake namespaces and each has some variables in it. e.g.

```
namespace :htmlNs do
  html_main = src_dir_html + "/main.html"
```

Obviously tasks in this namespace can use this variable. But how do I refer to html_main from other tasks in other namespaces?

I should emphasise that I am not talking about dependencies in other namespaces which works fine like ns:task